# Java Pattern Matcher single or multiple with comma separated

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have a string, which I need to parse, I want to use pattern matcher
need help with pattern.

if string as below:

```
sometext : test1,test2
```

output should be:

test1

test2

if input string is :

```
sometext : test1
```

then output should be :

```
test1
```

as you can see, it can be multiple or single.

Comment: Does your string include the `"sometext : "` part or is that just descriptive?

Comment: its part of that pattern

Answer (score 3):

So, you just need to replace `,` with a space? I would suggest a simple

```
String output = sometext.replace(",", " ");
```

If you need a newline after the first word, you can do

```
String output = sometext.replace(",", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

instead.

If `"sometext : "` is included in the input, you can get rid of that first in the same way:

```
String output = input.replace("sometext : ", "").replace(",", " ");
```

Comment: @user2063760: Why do you need a pattern specifically, it will make the solution more complicated. Also, a pattern by itself doesn't produce output, how do you want to use it?

Comment: my program have to parse big file and this is one line.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to separate "test1,test2" from "sometext", then use `replaceAll` to get the tests array by the `,` token.

```
String foo = "sometext : test1,test2";
String[] fooArr = foo.split("[:]"); 
String tests = fooArr[1];
System.out.println(tests.replaceAll(",", " "));
```

​

Comment: looking for pattern if possible, instead of string manipulation